# Ionic Native paypal, System Error, please try again later when logging in

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, paypal

I have tried implementing the Ionic paypal native plugin. I installed the plugin using:

```
ionic cordova plugin add com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk
npm install @ionic-native/paypal
```

The first day that I tried to use it, it worked perfectly fine. However after a day or two when I gave it to one of my teammates for testing, while trying to log into paypal (sandbox account), it keeps saying "Login Failed, System error. Please try again later". I have even tried the code snippet that is presented on the ionic documentation page, it gives me the same error.

```
import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from '@ionic-native/paypal/ngx';

constructor(private payPal: PayPal) { }

...


this.payPal.init({
  PayPalEnvironmentProduction: 'YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID',
  PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID'
}).then(() => {
  // Environments: PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork, PayPalEnvironmentSandbox, PayPalEnvironmentProduction
  this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
    // Only needed if you get an "Internal Service Error" after PayPal login!
    //payPalShippingAddressOption: 2 // PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal
  })).then(() => {
    let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
    this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {
      // Successfully paid

      // Example sandbox response
      //
      // {
      //   "client": {
      //     "environment": "sandbox",
      //     "product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK",
      //     "paypal_sdk_version": "2.16.0",
      //     "platform": "iOS"
      //   },
      //   "response_type": "payment",
      //   "response": {
      //     "id": "PAY-1AB23456CD789012EF34GHIJ",
      //     "state": "approved",
      //     "create_time": "2016-10-03T13:33:33Z",
      //     "intent": "sale"
      //   }
      // }
    }, () => {
      // Error or render dialog closed without being successful
    });
  }, () => {
    // Error in configuration
  });
}, () => {
  // Error in initialization, maybe PayPal isn't supported or something else
});
```

I tried different configurations, I also tried different developer account but it still gives me the same error. I apologize if this explanation is not so good since this is my first post, but please can you aid me in solving this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @ionic-native/paypal

The old mobile SDK plugin used by this has been deprecated for years and is end of life as of precisely today (Dec 7th). This integration cannot be used, it is completely sunset.

---

In switching over to a current supported [web-based PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) integration, ensure you [open it](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications) in a Safari View Controller or Chrome Custom Tab. (WKWebView or similar cannot be used)